# dart oauth facebook twitter login

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I would like to enable login via facebook and login via twitter for my web application which is built using dart. How do i do this using oauth2 package ?

Thanks in advance !
Ravindra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling your best bet would be to fully interact with the facebook javascript sdk with js-interop http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/

Comment: I agree i was able to use it.

Comment: Did you write a wrapper @user1560752? Can you share code?